# How to extract values from method in Angular ngFor

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I am trying to implement drop-down using method but it returns empty.
If I try to put inside ngOninit I lose my snapshot router values and not able return 200 result.
I putted inside constructor it returns values but I again lose my values.

I got result like this (works fine):

```
 [{"hypervisorName":"Steve","hypervisorId":1},{"hypervisorName":"Docker","hypervisorId":2}, 
   {"hypervisorName":"kubernetes","hypervisorId":3}]
```

My back-end method:

```
 [HttpGet("hyperforvm")]
 public IActionResult GetHypervisorsForVm()
 {
        var model = from hyper in _context.Hypervisors
                   select new 
        { HypervisorName = hyper.Name, HypervisorId = hyper.HypervisorId };
          return Ok(model);
 }
```

My component:

```
export class AddVmComponent implements OnInit {
  model: any = {};
  disabledProperty: boolean = true;
  items: any;

  constructor(private alertify: AlertifyService, private vm: VmService, private route: 
   ActivatedRoute, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.items = this.getHyper()
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let projectId = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('projectId')
    this.model.projectId = projectId
    this.model.managementId = 1    
  }

  getHyper() {
    this.vm.getHypervisorsForVm().subscribe(h => this.model = h)
  }  
}
```

My Html looks like:

```
    <div class="input-group mt-1">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text">
          <i class="fas fa-dot-circle text-info"></i>&nbsp;Hypervisor
        </div>
      </div>
     <select class="form-control" >
       <option disabled>-Please choose hypervisor-</option>
       <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.hypervisorId">
        {{ item.hypervisorName }}
       </option>
     </select>
    </div>
```

Situation is I need to save hypervisorId to db and in drop-down show hypervisorName (backend is ok tested with postman evrything is ok).Problems are does not matter I put inside constructor or ngOninit I lose my snapshot values. Inside constructor getHyper() method returns result but inside ngOninit not.
But both cases the values does not showing inside drop-down.
How to show hypervisorName save hypervisorId and beside them don't lose snapshot values.

Comment: You should do `ngFor` over _items_ not _Subscription_. Try something like this: `*ngFor="let item of model"`

Comment: you could call the method in constructor: `this.vm.getHypervisorsForVm().subscribe(h => this.items = h)`

Comment: @shrys thanks it helped one little thing I need to save hypervisorId but in my case I got exception 400 when I am trying to save if I a use simple input and manually add integer it works fine, so in this case I need somehow extract hypervisorId from getHyper() and save this id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed my html and it works fine now:

```
   <div class="input-group mt-1">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text">
          <i class="fas fa-dot-circle text-info"></i>&nbsp;Hypervisor
        </div>
      </div>
     <select name="hypervisorId" [(ngModel)]="model.hypervisorId" class="form- 
              control" >
       <option disabled>-Please choose hypervisor-</option>
       <option *ngFor="let item of model.items" [ngValue]="item.hypervisorId">
        {{ item.hypervisorName }}
       </option>
     </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should make an effort to remove  `any` types, doing this will greatly help you find bugs!.

With that said you can try this:

```
export interface Hypervisor {
  hypervisorName: string;
  hypervisorId: number;
}

export interface Projectmanagement {
  projectId: number;
  managementId: number;
}

export class AddVmComponent implements OnInit {
  hypervisors$: Observable<Hypervisor>;
  disabledProperty: boolean = true;
  model: Projectmanagement;

  constructor(
    private alertify: AlertifyService,
    private vm: VmService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private http: HttpClient)
  {
    this.hypervisors$ = this.vm.getHypervisorsForVm();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.model.projectId = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('projectId');
    this.model.managementId = 1;
  }
}

<div class="input-group mt-1">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text">
          <i class="fas fa-dot-circle text-info"></i>&nbsp;Hypervisor
        </div>
      </div>
     <select class="form-control" >
       <option disabled>-Please choose hypervisor-</option>
       <option *ngFor="let item of hypervisors$ | async" [value]="item.hypervisorId">
        {{ item.hypervisorName }}
       </option>
     </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not helped. However I have also class VirtualMachine instead of model I used this approach before, for strong typing I understand you, but I need just id for saving and this one throws exception exactly in hypervisorId, for ex if I manually enter id using simple input it works fine, I only want exclude id from method and save this id to db.

Comment: problem is it returns 0 when I select value from drop-down. It does not matter which value I select but it returns 0, but in  network I am getting actual id-s from db